# Count specific character of a file in each line and delete this character in a specific position

Tags: bash

I will appreciate if you help me here in this script in Solaris Enviroment.

Scenario:

i have 2 files :

1) /tmp/TRANSACTIONS_DAILY_20180730.txt:

```
201807300000000004 
201807300000000005 
201807300000000006 
201807300000000007 
201807300000000008
```

2) /opt/TRANSACTIONS_DAILY_20180730.txt

```
20180730|201807300000000005||50001521111200|0106276-4|5SIJ00|WIRE||EUR|EUR|20180730|20180730|||||||0000000000030 0.00|00000000000300.00|Credit||||||||||SIJ|||500015|506|||||||||||||||||||||||||FI3158410220205399||||FI|SME5
20180730|201807300000000005||50001521111200|0106276-4|5SIJ00|WIRE||EUR|EUR|20180730|20180730|||||||00000000000300.00|00000000000300.00|Credit||||||||||SIJ|||500015|506|||||||||||||||||||||||||FI3158410220205399||||FI|SME5
20180730|201807300000000006||50001521111200|0106276-4|5SIJ00|WIRE||EUR|EUR|20180730|20180730|||||||00000000000050.00|00000000000050.00|Credit||||||||||SIJ|||500015|506|||||||||||||||||||||||||FI3650005020017008||||FI|SME5
20180730|201807300000000007||50001521111200|0106276-4|5SIJ00|WIRE||EUR|EUR|20180730|20180730|||||||00000000000015.00|00000000000015.00|Credit||||||||||SIJ|||500015|506|||||||||||||||||||||||||FI1958410220026068||||FI|SME5
20180730|201807300000000008||50001521111200|0106276-4|5SIJ00|WIRE||EUR|EUR|20180730|20180730|||||||00000000000300.00|00000000000300.00|Credit||||||||||SIJ|||500015|506|||||||||||||||||||||||||FI8358410220212320||||FI|SME5
```

i) I want to read each line of the first file and if this "string" line will exist to the second file will put whole transaction of the second file to a new file.

ii) This new file that is created we will count the " | " characters in each line and if they more than 64 in each line , the 61 " | " in the specific line will be deleted.

I have managed to do the i) part of the script but i need help for the ii) part.

MY code until now for i) part which works:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do

grep "$line" /opt/TRANSACTIONS_DAILY_20180730.txt

done < /tmp/TRANSACTIONS_DAILY_20180730.txt > tmp/TRANSACTIONS_DAILY_NEW_20180730.txt
```

Comment: Have you investigated any of the text processing tools available, e.g. awk or python or perl?

Comment: i know that with this command with sed and combination with awk :

` sed 's/[^|]//g' /tmp/BadTransactions/TRANSACTIONS_DAILY_NEW_20180730.txt | awk '{ print length }' ` 

You can count how many times "|" is on each line

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Could you please share your idea here ?

Comment: Basically , my problem here is not how to count the " | " character but how to isolate the 61 position of  " | " character in each line so that i can delete it , if each line has more than 64 " | " characters.

Comment: The way I'd solve this is to use `awk` with the `-F` option to set the field separator to the `'|'` character.  That way you should be able to construct the desired output simply by printing the current word list with a suitable set of `'|'`characters placed between words.  Don't think in terms of deleting 61 of them, think in terms of keeping `N - 61` of them, and deleting the rest.

Comment: `grep -f` will save you a lot of time and code

Comment: Please suggest some code in my body .

Comment: With which command i can delete the 61 " | " ? 
Is there some command that i can delete 64 - 3 ?
tr command can help here ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bash-only answer, but consider reading about bash parameter expansion

```
if  [ ${a:60:1} == '|' ] ; then
   b="${a:0:60}${a:61}"
   # b is the new line shortened by removing 1 character.
   # the position starts counting from zero, length starts at 1
   # read about parameter expansion here:
   # 
fi
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-ParameterExpansion.html

Comment: You don't want to replace the character on position 60, but the 60th `|` in the string when you have at least 65 of them.

Answer (score 0):

First get removing the `|`working.
You can test with a smaller testfile:

```
$ cat testfile
Target: remove 4th | (after the 4) when 6 | are present.
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8
1|2|3|4|5|6|7
1|2||4|5||7
1|2||4|5|6
1|2||4|5|
```

With `sed` you can match a regexpr like `([^|]*[|])` and recall this one with `\1`.
I have put the pipe in brackets `[|]`, so it will not be seen as an OR.
You do not want to repeat that pattern 61 times, so you will make a pattern containing a repeated number of patterns. You need to pay attention to the order that the fields are remembered:

```
$ echo "1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8" | 
   sed -r 's/(([^|]*[|]){3})([^|]*)[|](([^|]*[|]){2})(.*)/input=&\n1=\1\n2=\2\n3=\3\n4=\4\n5=\5\nrest=\6/'
```

Using a varibele for the "one field" pattern might make the command easier to read:

```
$ p='([^|]*[|])'
$ echo "1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8" | 
   sed -r 's/('$p'{3})([^|]*)[|]('$p'{2})(.*)/input=&\n1=\1\n2=\2\n3=\3\n4=\4\n5=\5\nrest=\6/'

input=1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8
1=1|2|3|
2=3|
3=4
4=5|6|
5=6|
rest=7|8
```

When the lines has enough fields, the line will be changed. We ignore matches 2 and 5.

```
$ echo "1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8" | sed -r 's/('$p'{3})([^|]*)[|]('$p'{2})(.*)/\1\3\4\6/'
1|2|3|45|6|7|8
```

The 4th `|` has been removed. You can also test this with your testfile

```
$ sed -r 's/('$p'{3})([^|]*)[|]('$p'{2})(.*)/\1\3\4\6/' testfile
Target: remove 4th | (after the 4) when 6 | are present.
1|2|3|45|6|7|8
1|2|3|45|6|7
1|2||45||7
1|2||4|5|6
1|2||4|5|
```

Nog modify the command into removing the 61 th `|` when more than 64 exists.

```
$ testfile=tmp/TRANSACTIONS_DAILY_NEW_20180730.txt
$ sed -r 's/('$p'{60})([^|]*)[|]('$p'{4})(.*)/\1\3\4\6/' ${testfile}
```

The first part (matching two files) can be done using the `-f` option of grep. 
Please try

```
$ grep -Ff /tmp/TRANSACTIONS_DAILY_20180730.txt /opt/TRANSACTIONS_DAILY_20180730.txt
```

You can combine the commands with

```
$ sed -r 's/('$p'{60})([^|]*)[|]('$p'{4})(.*)/\1\3\4\6/' <(
   grep -Ff /tmp/TRANSACTIONS_DAILY_20180730.txt /opt/TRANSACTIONS_DAILY_20180730.txt
)
```

EDIT:
Using `cut` can be done in a loop, but that will perform badly for large files

```
echo "WARNING: Slow while loop, demo purpose only."
while IFS= read -r line; do
  p="${line//[!|]/}"
  np=${#p}
  if (( np > 5 )); then
     printf "%s%s\n" "$(cut -d'|' -f1-4 <<<"${line}")" "$(cut -d'|' -f5- <<<"${line}")"
  else
     printf "%s\n" "${line}"
  fi
done < testfile
```

EDIT: OP tried to edit my answer with additional questions. His Solaris system doesn't support `sed -r` or `grep -f`.
I tried to find an answer but did not test on Solaris.

Using `ksh` or `bash` on Solaris might work with

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  # count pipes in line using var p with only the pipes.
  # This can be handled wih "tr" as well, using
  # echo "${line}" | tr -cd "|" | wc -c
  p="${line//[!|]/}"
  np=${#p}
  if [ ${np} -gt 64 ]; then
     printf "%s%s\n" "$(echo "${line}" | cut -d'|' -f1-60)" "$(echo "${line}" | cut -d'|' -f61- )"
  else
     printf "%s\n" "${line}"
  fi
done < tmp/TRANSACTIONS_DAILY_NEW_20180730.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Until now this code works for me :

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/xpg4/bin:/bin:/usr/bin

while read line
do

grep "$line" /tmp/BadTransactions/test_data_for_validation_script.txt

awk 'NR==FNR { K[$1]; next } ($2 in K)' /tmp/BadTransactions/TRANSACTIONS_DAILY_20180730.txt FS="|" /opt/NorkomC
onfigS2/inbox/TRANSACTIONS_DAILY_20180730.txt > /tmp/BadTransactions/TRANSACTIONS_DAILY_NEW_20180730.txt

sed '/\([^|]*[|]\)\{65\}/ s/|//61' /tmp/BadTransactions/TRANSACTIONS_DAILY_NEW_20180730.txt

done < /tmp/BadTransactions/TRANSACTIONS_DAILY_20180730.txt > /tmp/BadTransactions/TRANSACTIONS_DAILY_NEW_201807
30.txt
```

So until now if there are more than 64th pipes in each line , it delete the 61th pipe.

Now , i want to delete the 61th pipe in each line if the line has more than 64 pipes until the line reaches the 64 pipes in whole line

What i mean :

If a line has for example 67 pipes , it will delete the 61th pipe , then it will go again to the same line and now it will check that it has more than 64 pipes(which actually has 66 now ) and i t will delete the 61th pipe.

This will be continued until the pipes are more than 64.

Could you please suggest me any idea how to loop that ?

Thank you